# distinct is not working on the multiple table join with the descending order in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, distinct

I am having problem with fetching the distinct priorities which are mapped with the study
here is the query i have written to get the result but the result is fetching records in 
the ascending order but the inner query fetches it in the reverse order

and if i remove distinct i am getting the records in descending order 
can any one help me understanding what is happening 
and get it corrected

```
WITH Results AS
  (SELECT priority_fk,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY priority_fk DESC) AS RowNum
   FROM "priorities" P,
   "study" S
)
SELECT 
distinct priority_fk,
"RowNum"
FROM Results
WHERE RowNum > 0
  AND RowNum <= 0 + 100
```

Comment: Can you post your table definitions and perhaps sample data?  You are producing a `cartesian product` which is probably why you're having issues.

Comment: I don't see the join, you are linking both tables by a cartesian product. Is that what you want or is there a primary and a foreign-key? (`priority_fk` sounds as if it's a fk)

Comment: Unless you specify an order with `ORDER BY` you cannot expect the result to be sorted, and that is true even if the set you are selecting from is sorted. In this case you need an `ORDER BY` clause on the outer select.

Comment: yes i have to use the cartesian product only

Comment: the study table definition is  create study 
CREATE TABLE "study" (
"pk" INT    PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
"priority_fk" INT
);

CREATE TABLE "priorities" (
"pk" INT    PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
"name" VARCHAR(255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS)

Comment: The *only* `ORDER BY` that is guaranteed to affect the order that results are produced in is the one on the outermost `SELECT` statement - all others are just part of the definition of other features (such as `TOP`, `FETCH` or `OVER()`) - computing those results may require sorting to occur but there's no guarantee that SQL Server won't reorder the results afterwards.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever can you please explain it in depth

Comment: `ORDER BY priority_fk DESC` inside your `OVER()` is helping to define what row numbers are assigned to each row. It offers **no** guarantee of the order in which results are returned. If you want the results in a particular order, you have to ask for that by adding an additional `ORDER BY` at the end of your query - e.g. `ORDER BY RowNum`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I understood Damien_The_Unbeliever thanks for explaining so i will put the order by even at the end of the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Window functions are evaluated as part of the evaluation of the expressions in the SELECT list, before the DISTINCT clause is evaluated. As a best practice you should not specify both DISTINCT and ROW_NUMBER in the same SELECT clause, because the DISTINCT clause has no effect in such a case. Also as specified by @Klas explicit ‘Order By’ clause is a must to ensure presentational ordering among rows in a set so the same has to be included in your outer query.